# Error in smart commit on JIRA(JIRA and gitlab integration)

Tags: gitlab, jira, jira-plugin

I have integrated Jira with GitLab.

But when am trying for smart commit, am getting an error:

```
SMART COMMIT ERROR
```

As in:

[image: smart commit error]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCDMl.png):

Answer (score 0):

The [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/integrations/jira.html) mentions:

> You  can also use [Jira’s Smart Commits](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/using-smart-commits-960155400.html) directly from GitLab, as covered in the article [How and why to integrate GitLab with Jira](https://www.programmableweb.com/news/how-and-why-to-integrate-gitlab-jira/how-to/2017/04/25).
>
> If there are any errors during the processing of Smart Commits, they will be logged to Fisheye's error console.

So do check your FishEye logs, and make sure your comment follows the basic smart command syntax:

```
<ignored text> <ISSUE_KEY> <ignored text> #<COMMAND> <optional COMMAND_ARGUMENTS>
```